# How to shutdown windows using c program , where user enters the time

Tags: c

i've been learning c , and i want to create a c program , all it should do is to shutdown the computer after a certain user entered time.

i know how to perform an immediate shut down , using this code :

```
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
 system("C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\shutdown /s /t 00");
 return 0;
}
```

i create the .exe file , and execute , it runs fine. but i don't know how to shutdown after some time that the user enters. i tried the # operator as :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define shutown(x) system("C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\shutdown /s /t" #x);

int main()
{
  int t;
  printf("\n enter secs :");
  scanf("%d",t);
  shutdown(t);
}
```

but the program did not work.
i've never actually used # operator , but did search on it , here :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7e3a913x.aspx

http://www.complete-concrete-concise.com/programming/c/preprocessor-%E2%80%93-understanding-the-stringizing-operator

but , i'm still not sure if i'm using the operator correctly.

i'd also like to create a program , which would create a folder in windows with user entered name , but i was planning to use # operator , and i guess i'm doing
something wrong.

please tell me where am i going wrong , and any other logic to perform the same tasks.

thanks a lot !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `#` operator is a preprocessor operator, meaning it is all done at compile time. You cannot use the values from the user there. You actually end up with:

```
system("C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\shutdown /s /t" "t");
```

Which is definitely not what you want.

You actually want to have a local string buffer to which you will print the value, using something like `sprintf` and then calling `system(buffer);`

---

This will do what you want:

```
int main()
{
  int t;
  char buffer[100];
  printf("\n enter secs :");
  scanf("%d",&t); // Note that you need &t here
  sprintf(buffer, "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\shutdown /s /t %d", t); 
  system(buffer);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! The program worked. I did not know about sprintf function , guess it will help me a lot ! :)

Answer (score 0):

In your `#define` statement, `shutdown` is spelled `shutown` (copy+paste error?).

To use a variable in a `#define` macro, just put the name of the variable. Example:

```
#define shutdown(x) system("C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\shutdown /s /t" x);
```

but call any functions in the macro as if you were calling them elsewhere. It does not substitute `x` for the *value* of `t`, it substitutes it for the literal `t`. Therefore,

```
system("C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\shutdown /s /t" t);
```

will not work. You will need to concatenate the two strings with something like `strcat`.

You will need to `#include <string.h>` to use `strcat`, but after you've done that here's a modified `shutdown`:

```
#define shutdown(x) system(strcat("C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\shutdown /s /t ", x));
```

DISCLAIMER: I have not tested any of this code, it's just a general guide. There may be problems, but this is the gist of what will work. Treat it as psuedocode.

Comment: That won't work: `strcat` takes `char *` as the first parameter, and writes past it's null terminator. You are passing a string literal (`[static] const char * const`). It will likely fail to compile, but if it doesn't it will crash when you try writing to a read-only object. You need to allocate the space explicitly.

Comment: @mtijanic as I said, "There may be problems, but this is the gist of what will work."